# Disable Legacy Server Key

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I found that Firebase Cloud Messaging has two ways to send Push Notifications.

I am aware of how the two ways are working and I have already implemented and tested my app and server using both ways.

However, I am required to disable the "Legacy server key" way of sending messages.

I cannot find how to disable this using Firebase Console.

Is it possible to disable the Legacy way of sending Push Notifications? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to disable or even delete the Legacy Server Key from the Firebase Console. The Legacy Server Keys automatically get generated and tied to the project after creation.

There may still be a number of users (most coming from GCM) who still use the Legacy Server Key in their apps , which I believe is the reason why it hasn't been removed yet. Other than that, there is no other use for it as far as I know.

---

**Update**:

There is a way for you to delete the currently tied Legacy Server Key in your Firebase Project, however, I would like to point out that this might cause issues if not handled properly. Only do this if you are absolutely sure that you won't be using the Legacy Server Key ever again.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to your [Google Developers Console Page](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. After sign in, select the correct project on the upper right side. If you can't find it in *Recent*, go to the *All* tab.
3. After selecting the correct project, click on *Credentials* on the panel to the left. You should then see a list of keys, one of which is named `Server key (auto created by Google Service)`. If you check, this is the same Legacy Server Key visible in your Firebase Project.
4. From here, you can click on the *Pencil* or *Trash* icon.

If you click on the pencil icon, it will direct you to a page where you can choose to *Re-Generate* or *Delete* the key. Choosing to generate a new key would give you a new server key, where the change would also reflect in your Firebase Project, while also still having the option to revert to it (only within the 24 hours limit).

Choosing to delete the key would automatically generate a new one for you, but you won't be able to have the option to revert to it.

Comment: At least, can I regenerate the Legacy Server Key to invalidate an older Legacy Server Key?

Answer (score 9):

you have to enable the firebase messaging API from the google developer console
by clicking on the three dots and clicking on the "Manage API in Google Cloud Console"

after enabling the API go back to firebase and refresh then you will get the FCM key for messaging

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com?authuser=0&project=courseflutter-15e95&hl=en
2. Click enable
3. Refresh the page