# Firebase Cloud messaging NodeJS PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED

Tags: node.js, firebase, messaging

I am trying to send a push notification from my nodejs app to my android app using firebase-admin

I followed the instructions as follows

```
import firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';

import serviceAccount from '../../common/constants/pushKey.json';
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
```

and the pushKey is the json generated from

project settings -> service accounts -> firebase admin sdk -> generate new private key

However when calling

`firebaseAdmin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)`

I get the following error

```
<TITLE>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
". Status code: 401.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/Documents/ZebedeeApps/booty/node_modules/core-js/internals/wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js:37:62)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (/Users/chris/Documents/ZebedeeApps/booty/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js:28:43)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/chris/Documents/ZebedeeApps/booty/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/chris/Documents/ZebedeeApps/booty/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/Users/chris/Documents/ZebedeeApps/booty/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:279:16)
    at Object.createFirebaseError (/Users/chris/Documents/ZebedeeApps/booty/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors-internal.js:57:12)
    at /Users/chris/Documents/ZebedeeApps/booty/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:79:51
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/authentication-error',
    message: 'An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: "<HTML>\n' +
      '<HEAD>\n' +
      '<TITLE>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</TITLE>\n' +
      '</HEAD>\n' +
      '<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n' +
      '<H1>PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED</H1>\n' +
      '<H2>Error 401</H2>\n' +
      '</BODY>\n' +
      '</HTML>\n' +
      '". Status code: 401.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'messaging'
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This library works though https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-notification

Comment: did you manage to fix this? getting same error

Answer (score 2):

Needs to enable Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72901323/6890201

[image: Firebase configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and since Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) is now deprecated I tried hard to get Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) to work.

I got lucky with using getMessaging(app).send() method instead .sendToTopic() or .sendToDevice() because those are using legacy api.
More here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messaging_class

So in your case, this should work:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'; // I recommend you use initializeApp instead because admin is legacy
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase-admin/messaging';
import serviceAccount from '../../common/constants/pushKey.json';

const fbApp = initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const messaging = getMessaging(fbApp);

// message is defined as [BaseMessage][1] extended by [topic][2] or [token][3] or [condition][4]
const message = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello',
        body: 'World',
    },
    token: 'xxxaaa...x'
};

try{
    const result = await messaging.send(message);
    console.log(result);
}catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```